# Phonegap camera getPhoto from file manager error on Android

Tags: android, cordova, camera, image-file

I try to load an image file from the phone. And by using the example code (`Camera.sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY`), when a button is pressed, a popup showing that I can select to open "Photo Library" OR "File Manager" (some names like that, may differ across phone models and languages). I can get the returned image file if I select it via Photo Library (as the code indicated?), but failed if I use "File Manager". The error is saying "Unable to load local resources - `file://....`". (In contrast, the returned value from Photo Library is of the `content://` protocol).

Since users may randomly use one of the applications (and some images are not in photo library scope), how can I get it correct with both ways?

=======Update========

Just realize that the error is reported because I use the returned file handle to the image as the image source. And my phonegap app use a remote link as index.html, which is thus not allowed to load local resources (cross-domain issue).
So I need to upload it at background firstly and set the image source to the returned url instead...

Comment: you need realpath from PHOTOLIBRARY for that change in plugin

Comment: @AmitPrajapati Can you give some explanation and how to do that?

Comment: you are working on phonegap which version ?

Comment: sorry you can't update phonegap structure in 2.9.0 you must need to you > 3.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I updated, I use a remote page (e.g., `http://domain.com/index.html`) instead of a page in assets (e.g., `index.html`, in most PhoneGap documents and tutorials). So the `file://` protocol will meet *cross-domain restrictions* and cannot be loaded by the remote page. While the `content://` protocol has no such restrictions. I have to reorganize the architecture of my solution.